# Realm with Swift Error

Tags: swift, realm

I just created a new project and download and integrated the CocoaPods "RealmSwift". I get the following list of errors.

[image]

I have not added anything in my code. This is coming from Realm code. I am using Xcode 8 using Swift 3.0

Here is the Pod file:

[image]

If I say convert to Swift 3.0 then I get the following errors:

[image]

Comment: not sure what the problem could be but it looks like you're setting manually your target's swift version to 2.3. If you're using swift 3 you shouldn't need to do any manual changes in your Podfile

Comment: I can try again but in the documentation of the Realm for Swift they instructed to do that.

Comment: Check the Swift version you're using on your XCode project. If required the version 3, upgrade it in your Podfile. Sometimes you get errors like this one in Xcode the first time you open it. Run the project and the compiler will work and those errors will disappear.

Comment: I am using Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8

Comment: the code you used in your Podfile says `'2.3' #or '3.0'` - obviously you have to chose the version, which you'd like to use: 2.3 or 3.0

Comment: Even if I delete that code it does not work. I even changed it to 3.0 and still have errors.

Comment: Which version of Realm and RealmSwift did CocoaPods install? Podfile.lock should show the versions that were installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the documentation for [CocoaPods](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation) for RealmSwift may-be out of date when Xcode 8.1+ and Swift 3 is used. Step 3 **is no more needed** and you should skip it for this case.

i.e. you should now use (example):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RealmProjectAzam' do

    use_frameworks!
    pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

**Edit - addition information:**
Please note, after the above question has been posted, there was some additional discussion incl. Realm and the result is that Realm (thanks @realm!) has adjusted its Swift documentation to better face the above issue. Please see the updated instructions for Cocoapods installation at [realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation)

In short, to "solve" the above issue please:

Run ***pod repo update*** to make CocoaPods aware of the latest available Realm versions.

Comment: I tried it with that also and same result. Also, I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0